# Boat part what part is this?

Tags: part-identification, boat, identify-this

I own a boat with Mercury 90 motor. There is a red switch on the engine used as security to start the boat, very simple. I've lost this key and want to replace it, but have no idea what it is called. It is not the normal ignition key, but just a small red switch key.

1. What is this part called?
2. How could I find a replacement? (Should I look online, contact a dealer, check a scrap yard, etc.?)

**UPDATE:**

No, this is not what I'm after. What I mean is just a pure-plastic, red, small key with 2 wings on each side. It's inserted into the engine part behind in the boat for the motor to start.

Comment: You'll need to provide a picture of the area where ITS inserted then. I'm still pretty sure what you need is a kill switch key from your description. Maybe you don't need (or want) the lanyard portion, but the kill switch keys located on it provides the other portion of what you need to get your engine started.

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes called a **kill switch lanyard**. This is an Airhead Boat Kill Switch Keys with Lanyard. It has seven keys which will fit most any outboard. There are others as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a **battery cutoff switch** - usually a red plastic t-shaped key about 2 inches across. There's various different sorts, but a bit of hunting on the web ought to find one that matches yours, and the keys are often available as spares...